# How do I add custom dimensions to Google Analytics with React Router?

Tags: google-analytics, react-router

My current analytics setup looks like this:

```
this.context.router.listen(location => {
  analytics.page(location.pathname, {
    title: document.title,
    url: `${config.HOST_URL}${this.context.router.createHref(location)}`,
    path: this.context.router.createHref(location),
    referrer: document.referrer,
    state: location.state,
  });
});
```

The amount of data in the `location` object is pretty minimal. The question is, how do I get information about an item that is loaded in a `componentDidMount` block into the page tracking?

In this particular instance, I am trying to add information about an artwork that a user is looking at into Google analytics as a custom dimension. The link below shows how it would normally be added.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#example-hit

I'm using react-router v2

Answer (score 0):

From the information given, I'd say your best bet is on the pages you want to add more data put a condition in the listener to NOT log if loading that page. Then in the componentDidMount where you have the data call the analytics for the page.

Basically just override it for those pages that need more data.